# Delete specific number of characters after a specific string is found

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have several lines of code and I'm looking for a way to search for a specific string e.g. 'id0=' and delete it and all 10 characters after it, per line. I would prefer a way/macro/addon for notepad++. But all other tools or scripts are welcome.

Note that ideally I'd like to delete and replace it with a 32 character string throughout the file, but for now, I'm just trying to get over the 1st hump, which is to delete it

Before

```
://81.88.22.6/*=id0=CB5B9C00BA
://*-ad.cgi*=time=3C8EFF48B674A820E7
://*-ads/*=id0=0D6CF7D5BE
```

Note that the patterns (numbers & characters) I'm looking for are always different per line and are not on every line so you couldn't do a search 'n replace with them.

Should look like this after

```
://81.88.22.6/
://*-ad.cgi*=time=3C8EFF48B674A820E7*
://*-ads/
```

I've tried this method, (try `=id0=[0-9A-Z]{10}`), which I've found on this site, but it's not working for me.

I'm using Notepad++ and in the replace GUI, I click on regular expression (radial button), then under *Find* I put `id0=[0-9A-Z]{10}` and leave the *Replace* field blank, but it does NOT seem to recognize `id0=[0-9A-Z]{10}` – it's not finding any!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, Notepad++ does not seem to understand the {10}.
But see if this works out for you, it seemed to in my quick test:

```
id0\=\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w
```

You have to escape the = sign i believe and the \w is just any one alphanumeric char or underscore.

This helped me:

http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/editors/understanding-regex-with-notepad/

Comment: This: id0=[0-9]{10} and you've suggested above seemed to work! Thanks Bro!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark an answer as the correct one then. Cheers

Comment: "Please mark an answer as the correct one" how do I do that?

Comment: No precise idea, didnt ask any questions yet. Should be easy enough to find i think. Maybe someone else can point you in the right direction.